# Difficult SQL query without cursors, cycles, etc in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Here is table:

```
Product_ID  Operation_Type   Operation_Sum    
1             ‘in’           100.00    
2             ‘in’           200.00    
3             ‘out’          50.00    
4             ‘in’           100.00
```

I have to calculate income.

Result table must look like this:

```
Product_ID  Operation_Type  Operation_Sum      Summary
1           ‘in’            100.00             100.00
2           ‘in’            200.00             300.00
3           ‘out’           50.00              250.00
4           ‘in’            100.00             350.00
```

If I wound not have column ‘Operation_Type’, if I had to calc only growing income, I would write next query:

```
select Product_ID, Operation_Type, Operation_Sum,    
(    
select sum(Operation_Sum) from Table1 as t1 
where t1.Id <= Table1.Id    
)    
from Table1
```

But I have ‘Operation_Type’. And I Cannot use cursors, cycles, temporary tables, etc.
It must be only one query.

What to do?

Comment: What defines the ordering of your rows, i.e. why does 2 occur before the second 1 (as an example)?

Comment: what version of SQL server? 2012 there's running totals...

Comment: What's the reason behind your restriction to a single query? It sounds like an academic (homework) problem.

Comment: its requirement of team leader.

Comment: Examples of some methods: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c0bdbd65-4f44-4380-8218-a90eb1281ed4/recursive-cte-for-running-totals?forum=transactsql

Comment: Avoiding cursors is generally good, but disallowing temp tables and other useful constructs seems like a somewhat arbitrary condition to impose upon developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your dbms support window functions, and there is a well defined ordering (product_id):

```
select product_id, op_type, op_sum
     , sum(case when op_type = 'in' then 1 else -1 end * op_sum) 
           over (order by product_id) as summary 
from t;
```

Comment: @Sasha, mark the answer as accepted. That way people will know that it was a solution to your problem ( and my reputation will benefit from it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you're using, so the quality of this answer may vary depending upon what dialect of sql it supports.  Also, I'm not sure if this is possible w/o some additional columns (order_date specifically.  With those in place however, here's one possible way to do it.  It uses correlated subqueries, which can be notoriously slow.  Its likely much faster to use a temp table, but if you truly cannot, here's how.

```
 select product_id, operation_type, operation_sum, op_date,
     summary = (select sum(operation_sum) from 
            product_operation where op_date <= t.op_date and operation_type='in') 
            - 
            coalesce(
                (select sum(operation_sum) from 
                 product_operation where op_date <= t.op_date and operation_type='out')
            , 0)
 from product_operation t
```

Its for SQL Server specifically.